OKTA sign in Widget error while loading login page
I have been integrating OKTA sign in widget in Angular and after updating to latest version npm install @okta/okta-signin-widget@latest, when I rerun it , gave me error
Probably from the networks I could find that there might be problem hitting this API
https://dev-53779339.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/interact
and error says
{"errorCode":"E0000022","errorSummary":"The endpoint does not support the provided HTTP method","errorLink":"E0000022","errorId":"oae3P3HrjrQRhiCt4ac0HN0Yw","errorCauses":[]}
Also getting this error in console
Sign-in error: OAuthError: The requested feature (Interaction Code flow) isn't enabled in this environment. Ensure that you have Okta Identity Engine enabled and the Interaction Code flow enabled for this application and authorization server.
